# remove zero line from ios charts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I've created a simple small chart using (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts), where i'm trying to remove everything beside the line itself, but i can't seem to remove the bottom zero axis. i've looked through the documentation, but cannot seem to remove it?

[image]

**chart**

```
class CellChartView: UIView {

    var lineChart: LineChartView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.lineChart = LineChartView()
        lineChart.backgroundColor = Color.lightTheme.value
        lineChart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.lineChart.chartDescription?.text = ""
        self.lineChart.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        self.lineChart.legend.enabled = false
        self.lineChart.minOffset = 0

        self.lineChart.drawBordersEnabled = false
        self.lineChart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
        self.lineChart.autoScaleMinMaxEnabled = true

        self.lineChart.rightAxis.enabled = false

        self.lineChart.leftAxis.enabled = false
        self.lineChart.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        self.lineChart.leftAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.green

        self.lineChart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
        self.lineChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        self.lineChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        self.lineChart.xAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = false
        self.lineChart.xAxis.enabled = false

        self.lineChart.xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.clear



        self.addSubview(self.lineChart)

        lineChart.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        lineChart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -1).isActive = true
        lineChart.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        lineChart.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setChartData(values: [Double], dates: [String]) {

        var yValues : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0 ..< dates.count {
            yValues.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i + 1), y: values[i]))
        }

        let data = LineChartData()
        let ds = LineChartDataSet(values: yValues, label: "Date")
        ds.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        ds.lineWidth = 1
        ds.drawValuesEnabled = false

        if (values.first ?? 0.0 > values.last ?? 0.0) {
            ds.setColor(Color.redColor.value)
        } else {
            ds.setColor(Color.greenColor.value)
        }


        data.addDataSet(ds)

        data.setDrawValues(false)
        self.lineChart.data = data
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to hide the xAxis, then I see two ways:

You could disable the xAxis  `xAxis.enabled = false`

Or set the xAxis line color to transparent `xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.clear`

Comment: i've tried both these things, none of this work, it does not remove the line

Comment: It's strange.I have tried to use your code (but LineChartView was created via storyboard) and bottom axis is not visible.

Comment: i've updated with the full `UIView` subclass, maybe you could reproduce using that? thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. I have tried to use you example and all looks ok. I coudn't see the horisontal red line. 
So, I can suggest that background color in your main view is red.  If you write `lineChart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -1).isActive = true` , then the lineChart view moves one pixel up and you see red background.  
I'm sure everything will be good if you change `constant` value from -1 to 0, e.g   `lineChart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true`

Comment: omg you are completely true, not sure how that slipped in, i've accepted answer. u can do a edit if feel for it :')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the horizontal and vertical lines being drawn through the center when you have disabled all grid lines and just want an X-Axis line as shown above in your drawing

```
lineChartDataSet.highlightColor = NSUIColor.clear
myLineChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
myLineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
myLineChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
myLineChartView.leftAxisAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
```

This will just hide the horizontal and vertical lines while giving you the freedom to draw a line through X-Axis or Y-Axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide background gridlines

Just do

```
    self.chartView?.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    self.charView?.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

It will remove background grids for both axis.[image] like that